# How to render a data table with multiple rowspan columns with ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, .net-3.5, webforms, html-table

I need to display data from a database in a html table. I am currently using a ListView control.

I want the final HTML table to render something like the following, where some rows have a `rowspan` attribute greater than one. The reason for this is that some fields have several rows of information, but correspond to the same logical entry.

For example:

```
|---------|---------|----------|----------|
| data    | data    |data      | data     |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|---------|---------|----------|----------|
| data    | data    |data      | data     |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|---------|---------|----------|----------|
| data    | data    |data      | data     |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|         |         |----------|          |
|         |         |data      |          |
|---------|---------|----------|----------|
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this in ASP.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not too elegant solution for `ListView`. The main idea is to use `Repeater` inside the `ListView` and bind all the sub-data(I mean data from the third column in your example) except the first record to it.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstData">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td <%# GetRowspan((int)Eval("Data.Length")) %>>
                <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
            </td>
            <td <%# GetRowspan((int)Eval("Data.Length")) %>>
                <%# Eval("LastName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# GetFirst((IEnumerable<string>)Eval("Data")) %>
            </td>
            <td <%# GetRowspan((int)Eval("Data.Length")) %>>
                <%# Eval("Country") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" 
            DataSource=<%# GetRest((IEnumerable<string>)Eval("Data")) %>>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and code behind:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    var item1 = new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", 
        Data = new[] { "first", "second", "third" }, Country = "US" };
    var item2 = new { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", 
        Data = new string[] { }, Country = "CA" };
    var item3 = new { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Public", 
        Data = new[] { "first", "second", "third", "fourth" }, Country = "US" };

    lstData.DataSource = new[] { item1, item2, item3 };
    lstData.DataBind();
}

protected string GetRowspan(int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return string.Format("rowspan='{0}'", length);
}

protected string GetFirst(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    return data.FirstOrDefault();
}

protected IEnumerable<string> GetRest(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    if (data.Any())
        return data.Skip(1);
    else
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

this outputs data in the format you want.

But if the usage of `ListView` is not necessary you could take a look onto `GridView`. There is more elegant way to do this by using it - [ASP.NET GridView RowSpan using RowCreated Event - How to add Table Dynamic RowSpan with GridView](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/asp-net-gridview-rowspan-using-rowCreated-event.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think GridView is going to be a better option as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
 var builder = new StringBuilder();
 builder.Append("<table>");
 for(int i=0;i<dt1.rows.count;i++)
 {
     builder.Append("<tr>");
     builder.Append("<td>");
     builder.Append(dt1.rows[i].ToString());
     builder.Append("</td>");

     builder.Append("<td>");
     builder.Append(dt1.rows[i].ToString());
     builder.Append("</td>");
     builder.Append("</td>");

     builder.Append("<table>");
     builder.Append("<tr>");
    for(int j=0;i<dt2.rows.count;j++)
    {
       builder.Append("<td>");builder.Append(dt2.rows[j].ToString());
       builder.Append("</td>");
    }
    builder.Append("</tr>");
    builder.Append("</table>");
    builder.Append("</tr>");
}
builder.Append("</table>");
output.Write(builder.ToString());
}
```

assume that dt1 as table1 and dt2 as inner table ...
so approach will help u out ...

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping there was a way to do this with ListView or another server control