# Merging of Duplicate data in a single column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, we are getting the result as shown here:

[image: Image1]

But, we need the output as shown here:

[image]

Is there any way we can merge the duplicate data through asp.net front-end or through SQL Query / Stored procedure?

Comment: You could use a nested `GridView` for the ID and Qty.

Comment: Refer to this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074403/how-to-render-a-data-table-with-multiple-rowspan-columns-with-listview

Comment: @TimSchmelter : Can you Please elaborate? I mean a example or a link where i can find exact Output shown above.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the preferred solution but it may help you to get data in more appropiate way:

```
SELECT * FROM [{yourDb}].[dbo].[{yourTb}] ORDER BY ProductName ASC
COMPUTE sum(Quantity) BY ProductName
```

Result :
Item  OrderId  Quantity

### Banana  31       2

Sum
6

--
continued

Item  OrderId  Quantity

### Apple  33       5

Sum
21

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that's not what i want. I an able to find the values required, but i want the UI to show the output as shown above in Image2

Comment: or perhaps Using SQL Server query/Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can return two tables from stored procedure , one table is having only product detail with total field and another one is having order detail.

Put grid with inner grid.

Now bind parent grid with product table and 2nd grid with order table, 
it will solve your problem.